# Arquitectura de aplicación android que consume un Websocket Service

Tags: android, firebase, websocket, aws

EDITO: Perdón por ponerlo en inglés.

Me gustaría hacer una aplicación en Android que consuma un WebSocket Stream (de terceros). El stream da información sobre precios y la aplicación se encargaría de notificar a los usuarios cuando un precio alcance cierto nivel.

Por ejemplo: Indico a la aplicación que quiero que me notifique cuando el precio del producto X baje de 10 euros.

Entonces, la aplicación estaría escuchando el WSS y mandaría un push al móvil del usuario cuando el precio baje de 10 euros.

Ya he probado con Firebase, pero no me termina de convencer, ya que no hay forma de poder mantener mi base de datos de precios actualizada a tiempo real con el WSS.

Así que tengo 2 preguntas:

¿Sería demasiada carga para la batería implementar la escucha del WSS en el móvil en lugar de en un servidor externo? Así me ahorraría toda la parte de servidores. El problema que veo es que es una aplicación simple, pero estar continuamente escuchando no me da buena sensación en cuanto al consumo de batería.

Si la respuesta es sí: ¿Que otras herramientas (aparte de Firebase) pueden ayudarme a hacer este tipo de aplicaciones? He leído algo sobre Kinesis y Lambda, dos herramientas de AWS, pero no estoy muy seguro de si encajarían con lo que busco.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinion tener el movil con una tarea en segundo plano escuchando constantemente si han cambiado los precios no es una buena práctica.

En lo que yo conozco una buena opción es que montes un servidor con [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr).

SignalR es un sistema que hace que el servidor mande informacion a los clientes sin que estos hayan pedido datos previamente, de esa manera tu servidor esta escuchando constantemente el WSS (imagino que no solo en una cotización, sino en muchas) y cuando detecta un cambio en una notifica a todos los clientes moviles que estan suscritos ese cambio.

No he probado SignalR en android nativo, pero si en Xamarin Android y es bastante comodo de manejar.

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573823/how-to-use-signalr-in-android) hay un post que parece bastante bueno de como implementarlo en android.